# Windows 10 alt-tab works slow

Tags: windows, windows-10, operating-systems, alt-tab

When I use alt-tab, my screen stops working for few second and only then, moves to the next program. When I restart the computer it works well for few minutes and then works slow again. Someone knows how to fix it?.
(The slow alt-tab don't have a connection to the program that I use when I do it).

Comment: What other applications are you running that the time? Have you tried having the task manager open to check the resource usage? Have you updated your graphics drivers?

Comment: Also run the standard Windows 10 initial repair procedures. From an admin command prompt, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by SFC /SCANNOW.  Restart and test after this and updating drivers.

Comment: I ran the following commands and the SFC /SCANNOW said that no problems were found. it is ok?

Comment: That is good and means (most of the time) no operating system problems. Update all your drivers and if that does not fix the issue, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link

Comment: I ran the following commands, updated the graphics driver, I did a restart and it is still works slow. there is another option except repair the windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found that killing the Cortana process stopped this from happening

Answer (score 0):

Too many open windows may cause this problem. I could see that if most of them are minimized, alt+tab becomes much faster.

Also based on [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/alt-tab-gets-slower-over-time-not-related-to-video/58fa17de-0780-47a9-ae12-1e6b77dc2b22) (and my experience), in Lenovo laptops, killing Lenovo-related processes improves alt+tab performance.